# Login Authentication Using Another Login Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm supposed to make  a React app: Login with Authentication.

In this React-App I need to put in email and password (that's done), then I need to make a fetch request using an API created by someone else, it's an ip address that asks for email and password, I guess I have to send the credentials I get in my Login-React-app and send to this IP Adress and retrieve 'ok' that's written when you login successfully.

Every time I try to find a question that could help me with this I come accross Authentication by IP Address and that's just not what I'm looking for...

Comment: Please show us some code what you are doing

Comment: All I've done is copying code off internet to try and do something similar. I can now perform fetch requests on JSON and html, I don't think this IP Address has any JSON and the body is empty given that the login is just a pop-up: http://177.72.161.199:7770/login, not sure if it's accessible to you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.